# How to overwrite parent class property in child class before parent constructor is called?

Tags: java, constructor, overwrite

I have a `BaseClass` with `public static String` xxx property. `BaseClass` constructor needs to call some method with xxx property. And have a `ChildClass` which should rewrite `BaseClass` xxx property but it is too late if I do it in `ChildClass` constructor.

How can I change the `BaseClass` xxx property so the `BaseClass` constructor will use the value from `ChildClass` xxx?

```
BaseClass {

    public statis Strin xxx = "";

    public void BaseClass()
    {
        open(xxx);
    }

}

ChildClass extends Baseclass {

    // Need to rewrite this value to be used by BaseClass constructor
    public statis String xxx = "something else" 

}
```

`BaseClass` still uses its own value not the value from `ChildClass` in constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't want to change the value used by the baseclass.

Static fields can't be overridden. You can do it with non-static fields, and keep the static one as a default, like this:

```
class BaseClass {

    public static String DEFAULT_XXX = "";
    protected final String xxx;

    public BaseClass()
    {
        this(DEFAULT_XXX);
    }

    protected BaseClass(String xxx)
    {
        this.xxx = xxx;
        open(xxx);
    }

}

class ChildClass extends BaseClass {

    public ChildClass()
    {
        super("something else");
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you describe the code. I don't understand, what happened there. I don't insist on the static but need to have child value in parent constructor.

Comment: Yes, that's what the super(...) call does. It calls the parametrized constructor of the parent with a value specified by the child.

Comment: Ah yes it makes sense. But is necessary to have two constructors in parent class if I want to use it. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

A `static` block in the child class could be used.

```java
static {
    xxx = "something else";
}
```

This would be called before the constructor.

1. If the BaseClass contructor need to use the value declared inside the class:

```java
class BaseClass {

    public statis Strin xxx = "Hello";

    public BaseClass()
    {
        System.out.println(xxx);
    }

}

class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
    {
        xxx = "Bye";
    }

    public ChildClass(){
        System.out.println(xxx);        
    }

}
```

`new ChildClass()` would output

```
Hello
Bye
```

2. If the BaseClass constructor should also use the value reset by the ChildClass then the child class should be updated as:

```java
class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
    static {
        xxx = "Bye";
    }

    public ChildClass(){
        System.out.println(xxx);        
    }

}
```

`new ChildClass()` would output:

```
Bye
Bye
```

Comment: That would overwrite the value of the baseclass as well, so when a BaseClass is instantiated later, it would use the value of the ChildClass.

Comment: Thanks for help. But static is not the right way as @GreyFairer says.